# Calling several services in one docker-component file in turn

Tags: java, linux, docker, makefile, docker-compose

help me please, I have one docker-compose a file. It has 2 test services and 2 workers. And there is a script. I need to make a sequential call: i.e. at first when I make docker-compose up 2 test services (post-service-test and rabb-service-test) should go up, then a script should run (it builds the application based on these running test services), then I need to stop and delete these test services and only then I have to raise 2 working services (post-service and rabb-service). Can you please tell me how to do this, having this kind of docker-compose file:

```
     version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: post-service
    image: postgres:9-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/db_migration/cdp_dump.sql:/home/postgres/cdp_dump.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - work_network
    labels:
      container_group: work_env


  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabb-service
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - work_network
    labels:
      container_group: work_env


  postgres_test:
      container_name: post-service-test
      image: postgres:9-alpine
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      networks:
        - test_network
      labels:
        container_group: test_env


  rabbitmq_test:
      container_name: rabb-service-test
      image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
      environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      depends_on:
        - postgres_test
      networks:
        - test_network
      labels:
        container_group: test_env


networks:
    work_network:
    test_network:


  application:
    container_name: build
    image: openjdk:8-jdk
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=${RABBITMQ_HOST}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    volumes:
      - ${project_home}:/root
    command:
    /bin/bash < build_script
```

Maybe I wrote the script incorrectly in a file? The script itself looks like this and it's working, if you run it separately. But I need to add it here so that everything does docker-compose. The script itself:

```
  docker run --name build -i --net test-network \
-v ${project_home}:/root \
-e POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST} \
-e POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB} \
-e POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER} \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} \
-e RABBITMQ_HOST=${RABBITMQ_HOST} \
-e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER} \
-e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS} \
openjdk:8-jdk /bin/bash < build_script
```

And another question: can I do such commands as docker stop post-service-test, docker rm post-service-test, docker stop rabb-service-test, docker rm rabb-service-test (stop and delete test services) to execute separately, and also to place in docker-compose or it is impossible?

**Thank you in advance !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem, I understood how to make this.
I create one docker-compose.yml config file and run this:

```
1) docker-compose up -d rabbitmq_test
2) make build-script   (this is application in docker-compose.yml file)
3) docker-compose stop rabbitmq_test postgres_test
4) docker-compose rm -f rabbitmq_test postgres_test
5) docker-compose up -d rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have specified the `application` service at the wrong place inside your docker-compose file. According to your file, it is a part of the `networks` block instead of the actual `services` block. **tl;dr**: Move the `network` block below the `application` block in docker-compose file.
2. The flow that you're trying to achieve won't be possible with just docker-compose, and 1 docker-compose file. You should break it down into at-least 2 files and write something that would control the flow, probably a shell script or something. It would also help you in separation of concerns as test and working services will be in different files

So your configuration could look something like this

**docker-compose-test.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres_test:
      container_name: post-service-test
      image: postgres:9-alpine
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      networks:
        - test_network
      labels:
        container_group: test_env


  rabbitmq_test:
      container_name: rabb-service-test
      image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
      environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      depends_on:
        - postgres_test
      networks:
        - test_network
      labels:
        container_group: test_env 


  application:
    container_name: build
    image: openjdk:8-jdk
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=${RABBITMQ_HOST}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
   volumes:
      - ${project_home}:/root
   networks:
     - test_network
   command: /bin/bash < build_script


networks:
    test_network:
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: post-service
    image: postgres:9-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/db_migration/cdp_dump.sql:/home/postgres/cdp_dump.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - work_network
    labels:
      container_group: work_env


  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabb-service
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - work_network
    labels:
      container_group: work_env


networks:
  work_network:
```

(Example script you would need to control the flow)

**run.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yaml up -d
# Wait for container `build` to exit 
docker wait build
docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yaml down
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

**NOTE:**
Using [docker wait](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/) you can wait for your application container to exit so you know its safe to stop and remove the containers.

Comment: thank you for your help. But I need use 1 docker-compose.yml file (not two)

Comment: what you can do then is run another service/container, after the tests which has docker in itself, and then that service could control the "wait to exit" and then run the test containers. 
But this would be an ugly workaround